# Taking a full resolution picture while recording video

Tags: android, android-camera

I am not involved with progamming for Android yet, but I need to know in advance, if it is possible to take a full resolution picture (meaning maximum image resolution of the available camera), while recording video at full video resolution. The recorded video is not saved, but the video data is being processed.
If this is not possible, how long does it take to switch from video recording mode to picture mode?

Comment: In general, no. I believe I've seen ads for devices that *can* do this, but it would be very device-specific, and might only be available with the manufacturer's camera application.

Comment: Device-specific would not necessarily be a problem, using only the manufacturer's app would. Which devices should I look into?

Comment: Well, I know the Samsung Galaxy Camera can do it, but that's not a very popular device. I don't know any *phones* offhand. You might be able to find a comparison chart somewhere, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It is the standard scenario to start camera in "preview" mode and then take a still picture at higher resolution. Actually, you cannot take a stil picture without first starting the Android camera in preview mode. And you can receive preview frames in your callback, to do some processing.

Switch takes time, which depends on the device and on external conditions (e.g. it may be much longer at night) and focusing logic (autofocus may be painfully slow in certain setups).

On modern phones, capture may take less than 100 ms.

**Update:** Here is a simple try on an Galaxy S4 device, with the original camera app, auto mode, photo size 3264x1836, ISO=auto...

```
time, ms 

561      takePicture start
796      camera notification
836      CAMERA_MSG_COMPRESSED_IMAGE
901      previewEnabled (again)
```

Comment: Which quality are the preview frames in? Essentially I need full video resolution (720p or 1080p, depending on camera) first, process the frames as they arrive, and then I may need full image resolution (5MP and up, depending on camera) for a single picture afterwards on demand, and then process the image. "Switch takes time" - that's probably at least several 100ms, right?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an exctract from the device log on my S4. Note that 340 ms is the round-trip: from the moment I clicked "capture" to the moment that the application was back in the preview mode. The preview quality and resolution depend on the device, but I believe that chosing max available preview resolution does not make switch to capure slower.

Comment: So at 561ms the camera was in preview-mode (with video settings), at 836ms the (high-resolution) picture was taken, and at 901ms it was back in preview-mode(with video settings)? If so, that's a valueable information, thanks for testing!